# How can I connect local Airflow with Hive in a Docker container to execute HiveOperator query?

Tags: python, docker, hive, airflow, etl

I have an ETL, most of the tools are launched in docker containers, except airflow that is running in local.
my hive setup in compose.yml:
`

```
hive-server:
    image: bde2020/hive:2.3.2-postgresql-metastore
    container_name: hive-server-analysis
    env_file:
      - ./cluster_config/hadoop-hive.env
    environment:
      HIVE_CORE_CONF_javax_jdo_option_ConnectionURL: "jdbc:postgresql://hive-metastore/metastore"
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "hive-metastore:9083"
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:10000:10000
    expose:
      - 10000
    depends_on:
      - hive-metastore
  
  hive-metastore:
    image: bde2020/hive:2.3.2-postgresql-metastore
    container_name: hive-metastore-analysis
    env_file:
      - ./cluster_config/hadoop-hive.env
    command: /opt/hive/bin/hive --service metastore
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:50070 datanode:50075 hive-metastore-postgresql:5432"
    expose:
      - 9083
    depends_on:
      - hive-metastore-postgresql
  
  hive-metastore-postgresql:
    image: bde2020/hive-metastore-postgresql:2.3.0
    container_name: hive-metastore-postgresql-analysis
    depends_on:
      - datanode
```

Is it possible to connect local airflow to hive (localhost:10000) hosted in docker to execute a query with HiveOperator? i tried setting the connections in the airflow UI (hive_cli, hiveserver2) but all of them need hive in localhost, or so i think.
If i try with my custom connection based on hiveserver2, the following exception is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/hive/operators/hive.py", line 165, in execute
    self.hook.run_cli(hql=self.hql, schema=self.schema, hive_conf=self.hiveconfs)
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/hive/hooks/hive.py", line 279, in run_cli
    sub_process: Any = subprocess.Popen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hive'
```

And if i try with hive_cli:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/hive/operators/hive.py", line 165, in execute
    self.hook.run_cli(hql=self.hql, schema=self.schema, hive_conf=self.hiveconfs)
  File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/hive/hooks/hive.py", line 279, in run_cli
    sub_process: Any = subprocess.Popen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'beeline'
```

Any ideas?